# Set the Continuous Crawl Interval in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, enterprise-search

I ran below command to set the Continuous Crawl Interval in SharePoint 2016:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$interval = "1"
$ssa.SetProperty("ContinuousCrawlInterval", [int]$interval)
```

But in Search service application, content source "Local SharePoint sites" does not showing any interval set.
Even on Search Administration page no Recent crawl rate and no Searchable items shows and in Crawl Log page everything shows 0.
Please guide.

Comment: The snippet seems correct, but you missed the `Update` call.

Answer (score 3):

You can try below powershell code:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$cs = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity "Local SharePoint sites"
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -Identity $cs -EnableContinuousCrawls $True


$ssa.SetProperty("ContinuousCrawlInterval", 1)
$ssa.Update()
```

Reference- [Enable continuous crawls with PowerShell](https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/enable-continuous-crawls-with-powershell)

Comment: hi @prakash, did you try the above code, is it working for you ?

Comment: glad i could help, if it worked, could you please mark/accept it as an answer so that it doesn't show up  in the unanswered section, its the checkmark below the upvote button ?